# How to create a chart for showing sigma value like this

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, amcharts

I need to create a stacked bar chart to show [Six Sigma value](https://www.dummies.com/article/business-careers-money/business/project-management/how-to-calculate-six-sigma-quality-171304?fbclid=IwAR0U0j0Ddpgssl7BZNPMq-xQ1Jf8wP13o2aEgXCrWiLInllEKUwoNgF-jsM) as shown in the image

[image]

Here the values in the Y axis are static. But the values in the X axis are not evenly spaced. The image is not properly designed. I am attaching a picture to illustrate the values of the X axis according to the value of the bars. In the picture the yield column corresponds to the values on the bars.
[image]
Also I need to show the values on the bar as shown in the image.
I have tried to use chartjs 2 but I can not figure out how to make a custom spacing scale for the X axis.

My attempt at modifying the X axis ticks is given below

```
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      yAxisID: 'yAxis'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        position: 'right',
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Any recommendations other than chartjs for this functionality would also be highly appreciated

Comment: actually i have heard of `chart.js`, `apexchart`, `syncfution` and `Echart` for implementing charts have you seen their demos?

Comment: some examples for `apexchart` sigma chart. https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/bar-charts/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but we solved this using html, css and some front end logic later